# Remove Lipsum from this

Tags: blank-page, lipsum

USING OverLeaf 2
I want to use this format to create a letter head. And I can't remove the lipsum text. If I remove the

\usepackage{lipsum} line and the \lipsum[1]

I get compile errors.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{maxlink}{RGB}{2,60,180}
\usepackage{tikz}               % you know what this does!
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}         % put things headers and footers and we plan misuse it ;)
\usepackage{lipsum}           % for sample text 

\fancypagestyle{mypage}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LO]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \fill [color=maxlink] (current page.north west) rectangle
                ($ (current page.south west) + (0.4cm,0cm) $);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
   \fancyhead[RE]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \fill [color=orange](current page.north east) rectangle
                ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,0cm) $);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mypage}   % activate colored margins
\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}    % deactivate colored margins
\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
\pagestyle{mypage}   % activate colored margins
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are three `\lipsum[1]` lines. Replace each one with a letter or a word (otherwise a PDF with size 0 will be written, because there is nothing on the pages to ship out); it does compile here.

Comment: That's what I did. I put a period (.).. Is there no way to just create a blank page with the "mypage" style?

Comment: Please see [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/525701/73317) below.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want three pages with nothing but the colored rectangles drawn with Ti*k*Z from the `mypage` page style? And maybe you don't want anything on the second page, or just a page number in the footer?

When you remove the `\lipsum[1]` on a given page, there is no contents anymore on the page. A subsequent `\clearpage` does not output any page to the PDF file. So, if you simply remove the three `\lipsum[1]`, the result is a PDF file with size 0, which is invalid. A simple fix for this is to replace each `\lipsum[1]` with `\mbox{}`—that is, an empty box. This is enough to decide TeX to ship out a page.

So, if you remove `\usepackage{lipsum}` and replace all three `\lipsum[1]` with `\mbox{}`, you'll get this:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{maxlink}{RGB}{2,60,180}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{mypage}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LO]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \fill [color=maxlink] (current page.north west) rectangle
                ($ (current page.south west) + (0.4cm,0cm) $);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
   \fancyhead[RE]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \fill [color=orange](current page.north east) rectangle
                ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,0cm) $);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{mypage}   % activate colored margins
\mbox{}

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}    % deactivate colored margins
\mbox{}

\clearpage
\pagestyle{mypage}   % activate colored margins
\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second page has nothing but a page number at the bottom, because it uses `\pagestyle{plain}`.

- If you don't even want the page number, use `\thispagestyle{empty}` for the second page (`\pagestyle{empty}` would do the same if you use `\pagestyle` on the following page).
- In case you want to see the orange border prepared by the `mypage` style on the second page, simply use the `mypage` style for all three pages:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{maxlink}{RGB}{2,60,180}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{mypage}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LO]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \fill [color=maxlink] (current page.north west) rectangle
                ($ (current page.south west) + (0.4cm,0cm) $);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
   \fancyhead[RE]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \fill [color=orange](current page.north east) rectangle
                ($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,0cm) $);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{mypage}   % activate colored margins
\mbox{}

\clearpage
\mbox{}

\clearpage
\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry. I know this is unrelated. But how would I go about putting also a picture in the header.

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}%` before one of the `\begin{tikzpicture}`. You may then need `\setlength{\headheight}{something}` (see `fancyhdr` manual) or make TeX believe that the image takes no space. Package `atbegshi` can be useful too.